# How to use symfony controller file routes from file opened in CLI

Tags: php, symfony, socket.io, doctrine

I am working on project based on symfony in this project I want to use socket.io with symfony for this purpose I use PHPSocketIO.

Now I want to store data in database when new user login. Socket.io server that I am using for communication between client  and server is running in CLI mode on the server and I install PHPSocketIO by composer.

How I call compiler in CLI mode and run compiler routes?

My `server.php` file that is run in CLI mode is in the main directory of my symfony project directory.

Answer (score 0):

For all routes we have URL for each route. We send Get and Post requests to these URL.

I my case i use httprequests class to send post requests and it works for me.